# Checking value of datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am importing an excel file and in this excel,in one column, let's name it CodeName, has the possible values of A01, A02, B01, B02. Those are the only possible values

Is it possible to read the contents of the row in the datagridview and have a condition where I can only have A01, A02, B01, or B02?

Currently I am thinking;

```
 'READING every row TESTING
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If -----Then
             'MsgBox("content has wrong value")
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Are you using VB.NET or Excel-VBA? These are totally different applications, please clarify in your question and tags. Also I'm very sure that there are many tutorials out there that show how to fill a DataGridView. Try to use one of them and then come back with your real code, your error message and your question to it. Also have a look at [mcve].

Comment: what are you planning to do if it has the wrong value...remove it?

Comment: vb.net. importing the excel file is not the main question at hand. I am importing the excel file into the datagridview; but my question is about reading the contents that is filled in the datagridview so that it can only contain A/B 01 or 02.. I think it is much rather easier to read the contents in the cells of the DGV rather than prior to importing the excel file and having the popup msgbox saying wrong value ///

and if it has wrong value; just a pop up message, such as "MsgBox("wrong value")

Comment: You should just be able to check `If row.Cells("CodeName") = "A01" OrElse ... {repeating for each of your values}`. But if you load the data into a datasource using OleDb, you could just handle this in a SELECT statement and only bring in the rows that have CodeName = to those values.

Comment: Yes I am importing the excel file into the DGV through OleDbConnection. okay I  will try your suggestion; thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the comments it would be better to populate the `DataGridView` with a `SELECT` statement that only brings the rows with CodeName = YourValues

Although to answer your question which may help you in the future i would do something like this:

```
        For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If dgvRow.Cells("CodeName").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                MsgBox("Wrong Value")
            Else
                Select Case dgvRow.Cells("CodeName").Value
                    Case "A01", "A02", "B01", "B02"
                        'Do nothing
                    Case Else
                        MsgBox("Wrong Value")
                    End Select
            End If
        Next
```

I do a `NULL` check first off and then i would use a `SELECT CASE` statement, because when comparing something to several values I feel it's tidier than a list of `ElseIf`'s but that's entirely up to you.

You might not want a `msgBox` though as if would be rather annoying if there is a lot of rows that don't contain the values your looking for.

Maybe just set `dgvRow.Cells("CodeName").Style.BackColor = Color.Red` or something instead so you can see the wrong values and not have to click OK every time.

Comment: If you want me to delete this answer so Charles May can post his comment as the answer then that's fine :)

Comment: What if there is 500 rows of data? And of those 500 rows, only 6 of them have A01, A02, B01, B02. Would you really want to set there and click that OK button 494 times? I would at the very least put a rowfilter out there to only display what I want or instead of a messagebox, write in either "CodeName" or a new cell "Wrong Value" and possibly hilight it. The problem is, we've never received an answer on what we're going to do with "wrong value" rows.

Comment: I know i did state about not using a msgBox for that very reason, in his comment though he said "...and if it has wrong value just a pop up message, such as "MsgBox("wrong value") " so i just put it in there.

Comment: Yep, you did, sorry. I must be going blind in my old age.

Comment: I didn't really want to suggest what he should do instead, but personally i think i would probably set `Style.BackColor = Color.Red` for wrong values so i know there are wrong values and can see them.

Comment: @Pete Please correct your Select. It won't work as written because it is looking for a string to match "A01, A02, B01, B02" not the individual items. `Case "A01", "A02", "B01", "B02"`

Comment: @Mary wow i can't believe i did that! thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: oh I hadn't even thought of the style.backcolor method, I just thought of a pop up message. That's a pretty smart idea. thank you. I also understand both Pete's and @Mary method way. thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach... Define an array of the valid values then use the .Contains method of an array on each value you want to test.

```
    Dim arr() As String = {"A01", "A02", "B01", "B02"}
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not arr.Contains(row.Cells("CodeName").ToString) Then
            MsgBox("Wrong")
        End If
    Next
```